# Python performance problem: difference between two polygons

Tags: python, performance, shapely

I am currently using Python 3.7 and I want to find the difference between a lot of polygons. With that I mean that if I have a polygon **A** and a polygon **B** I want to do the mathematical **"A not B"** operation. There are two possible outcomes of this operation as seen in the following illustration:

[image]

So two polygons that I subtract ("cut") from each other either give me a new polygon or are empty. All other cases can be ignored. The form of the polygon does **not need to be exact** for case 1. So it is acceptable if the polygon changes a bit.

For case 2 I need to know if the polygon is empty.

Furthermore polygon A and B do not have any "holes" in them so they can be described by only their outside border.

I already built a prototype that uses [the `difference` operation of shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.difference) to do this. I "cut" exactly as little as possible (once for every two polygons).

My code is a bit complex but it basically breaks down to this simple function:

```
def cut_hole(A : Polygon, B : Polygon) -> Polygon:
    """
    Cuts a "hole" into shapely polygon A
    :return: The polygon resulting of the operation A-B. Might be empty!
    """
    outer = A #not in my code, just to point out what I mean
    inner = B
    return outer.difference(inner)
```

Now my problem is that this is very slow! I work with roughly **15.000** operations per batch (30.000 polygons) and I takes about 10 to 15 min to calculate them all. I would really like to go down to under 5 mins.

Please keep in mind that this does not account for all the other operations. 15 min just for the difference operation. I can sort every polygon A to every polygon B in under 1 min. I just need a quick way to get the resulting polygon from those.

I did this test with an "good" computer (Intel core i7, 16 GB Ram). Neither the CPU or RAM was at its limit.

So the big question is: how can I speed this up?

Is there a way to translate the polygons into a form that is easier to handle? 
Or is there a "better" way to get the difference of two polygons?

Is there an alternative library that might be better? Or can I get shapely to use other hardware? If so what kind of hardware might that be?

Finally my next step would be to try and parallelize the "cutting". Is there an build-in way to do this quickly and efficiently? Because I did not find one in shapely.

Also I would be very grateful for tips on analyzing possible bottlenecks.

**Addendum:**

Some of the polygons seem to be rather complex. With that I mean that at average the more complex polygons contain 15.000 points. The not complex polygons less then 100 points. However usually (as in 99 %) polygon type A or type B are not complex at the same time.

[Here is an example of an complex polygon in WKT](https://justpaste.it/7e7gk)

Comment: You can check if [speedups](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#performance) are available on your computer. For multiprocessing, see [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) package as there is none in shapely.

Comment: I think your problem lies elsewhere; I just did some tests on a normal computer and performing [`p1.difference(p2.buffer(np.random.rand()) for _ in range(15000)]` took 2,5s. Are your polygons overly complex ?  In this case, try to `simplify` them, as approximative results can be accepted in your case

Comment: Wait, speedups provides basically a "faster" button? Why isn't that enabled in the first place? Are there draw-backs? 
Also many thanks. I did not see that.

Comment: They are enabled by default when possible, but maybe it is not the case on your computer

Comment: My polygons are not that complex. They cover long distances tough. So I have a line-string with maybe 20 points but a length of a few thousand units.

Comment: Length shouldn't be a problem then.

Comment: I spoke way too soon: I have actually very complex polygons. Not all of them but a few are rather big.

Comment: I did try to post all my polygons into WKT but unfortunately the file ended up to be bigger then 5 GB and my internet connection can't upload that. I edited my post to show how complex my polygons are besides using the simplify method.

Answer (score 1):

Taking your points in order:

- I highly doubt there is another, better-suited format/library for manipulating polygons in python than shapely, it is the reference package. You can try to `simplify` your geometries, but some rapid tests showed it is a slow operation as well (`p`being the polygon you copypasted above):

  ```
  p2 = p.buffer(-10)                   # creating a 2nd polygon
  %timeit p.simplify(1)                # 58.4 ms, from 15000 to 8000 points
  %timeit p.difference(p2)             # 53.2 ms 

  %timeit p.difference(p2.simplify(1)) # 127ms
  %timeit p.simplify(1).difference(p2) # 114ms
  ```
- Shapely uses [GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) under the hood. Maybe you can try to dig in that direction for lower-level solutions.
- There is no parallelism in shapely. However as you seem to have your 'As' and 'Bs' polygons already matched, you can parallelize the shapely operation through a threadpool or processpool (see [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) package). If they are not matched, you can check it quickly through `intersects`(much faster than `intersection`or `difference`. If some of your polygons do not intersect, that will be a huge speedup.
- Considering the size of your data (5GB is a lot of geometries...), I don't think you can spare that much time other than with parallelization, as one `difference` takes ~70ms which gives ~1050s = 17 min for  15000 operations

Comment: Thank you very much for these insight. Given all this I think the best course of action is to write my own version of simplify which simply just picks every Nth point of the polygon as long as the deviation is low. If I get too much error I go-back by N/2 until I find a point. I may post once I worked on this.

Comment: Actually kind of. I managed to write a simplify method but it worked worse than the provided one. What I did do in the end was to scale down my starting image but I couldn't test it yet since I am needed on another project. I will get back to this once I handled that other project.

Comment: Might the PyGeos package help?  I plan to use it in the future.